# How to trigger a Jenkins job if other job was successful? (not automatically)

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have 2 Jenkins jobs which get triggered when different changes are pushed to GitHub (either one can also be run manually). Is it possible to make a job depend on the other one as well? Let's say I have job A and job B, I want A to be triggered when a push happens on GitHub (this is already working) and B to be triggered when a push happens on GitHub **only** if the last build of A was successful (so I don't want it to be triggered automatically after A)

Answer (score 1):

Could we skip the GitHub push checking on B? We checked it by A. Just trigger B if A was successful.

- A push happens on GitHub

  - Trigger the A

    - If the last build of A was successful, trigger B (use the curl tool...?)